# Django 1.8, mod_wsgi, apache 2.4 setup on CentOS 7 Not Working

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, centos7

I'm having a hell of a time with a server error that sounds like it has an obvious solution, but isn't working out that way:

```
[:error] [pid 10979] (13)Permission denied: [remote xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:20] mod_wsgi (pid=10979, process='testsite', application='xxx.xxx.xx.xx|/testsite'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/jnett/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py'.
```

For obvious reasons, I took out the actual server addresses.  I've set up so many django sites in RedHat, earlier CentOS distributions, OSX, and even Ubuntu, and took lots of notes in all cases.  Still, I cannot seem to get this configuration right.

So here it is:

1.
My apache configuration is

```
VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName xxx.xxx.xx.xx
ServerAlias *.xxx.xxx.xx.xx
WSGIDaemonProcess testsite python-path=/home/jnett/testsite:/home/jnett/airview_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /testsite /home/jnett/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py process-group=testsite
Alias /static /home/jnett/testsite/static
<Directory /home/jnett/testsite/testsite>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Location /home/jnett/testsite/static>
    Options -Indexes
</Location>


/VirtualHost>
```

(I intentionally wrote "< VirtualHost >" as "VirtualHost >" for formatting issues here. )

2.
My `wsgi.py` file is located where it should be according to the above apache configuration and contains:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append( '/home/jnett/airview_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages' )
sys.path.append( '' )

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "testsite.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

3.
My user directory has permissions 755.

4.
My project directory `testsite` has 777 permissions (just as a sanity check here, which is driving my insanity on this problem) on the parent directory and recursively for everything inside.

Further, apache also has ownership.

```
~ ]$ls -all
drwxrwxrwx.  4 jnett  apache   50 Jan  4 22:23 testsite
~ ]$cd testsite/
~/testsite ]$ls -all
total 8
drwxrwxrwx. 4 jnett apache   50 Jan  4 22:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 9 jnett jnett  4096 Jan  4 23:56 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jnett apache  251 Dec 30 16:52 manage.py
drwxrwxrwx. 2 jnett apache    6 Jan  4 22:23 static
drwxrwxrwx. 2 jnett apache   70 Jan  4 23:56 testsite
~/testsite ]$cd testsite/
~/testsite/testsite ]$ls -all
total 12
drwxrwxrwx. 2 jnett apache   70 Jan  4 23:56 .
drwxrwxrwx. 4 jnett apache   50 Jan  4 22:23 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jnett apache    0 Dec 30 16:52 __init__.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jnett apache 2644 Dec 30 16:52 settings.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jnett apache  758 Dec 30 16:52 urls.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jnett apache  554 Jan  4 22:48 wsgi.py
```

5.
The django version is 1.8 and apache version is 2.4.

6.
selinux is set to `permissive`, because I know that can sometimes cause issues.

I've tried every possible little tweak to the above settings and to the permissions of everything it's pointing to, but I still cannot get any result other than the above "permission denied" error.  Yes, I've googled around as much as I could on this error; No, none of the things I found produced a solution.  Yes, I've also scoured the django and mod_wsgi documentation, so please don't just post a link and nothing else unless you noticed a specific obvious discrepancy.

I've staring at this for quite some time, so I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes can catch something I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Looks like you have the right permissions on the project directory itself, but it is inside your home directory which Apache can't access. Try putting it inside /srv/ or somewhere and make sure Apache can access the whole path.

Comment: It's a good thought, but even giving apache full ownership of my user directory doesn't change anything and I have my user directory set to 755 anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really was an selinux problem--I misunderstood how to set it to `permissive`.  Changing the value in `/etc/selinux/config` to `permissive` does NOT actually put selinux in a `permissive` state until the server is rebooted.